# call userenv('commitscn') failed in oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> insert into fullScnTmp(scn) values(userenv('commitscn'))
  2  ;
insert into fullScnTmp(scn) values(userenv('commitscn'))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 19029
Session ID: 276 Serial number: 46035
```

i want to get scn of current transaction by insert userenv('commitscn') to a temp table, but failed every time,and will be disconnect to oracle. userenv('commitscn') is not support in oracle 12c?

Comment: did you startup the DB, and checked for networking issues?

Answer (score 0):

What type of column are you storing the SCN into?  According to [this article from 1999](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/commit.html), it must be an unconstrained `number`.

Here's a quick session I ran on Oracle XE 18c.  If I create the table with a `number` column, it works fine:

```
SQL> create table fullScnTmp (scn number);

Table created.

SQL> begin insert into fullScnTmp (scn) values (USERENV('COMMITSCN')); commit; end;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from fullScnTmp;

       SCN
----------
   1566009
```

However if I recreate it with a `varchar2` column instead, the `ORA-03113` error occurs:

```
SQL> drop table fullScnTmp purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table fullScnTmp (scn varchar2(100 char));

Table created.

SQL> begin insert into fullScnTmp (scn) values (USERENV('COMMITSCN')); commit; end;
  2  /
begin insert into fullScnTmp (scn) values (USERENV('COMMITSCN')); commit; end;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 7748
Session ID: 275 Serial number: 59633
```